# High performances to interact with 10.000 objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg

I need to display on a web page about 10.000 circles. Each circle has to be bound to data. I also need to interact with my circles as following :

- change css if I mouse over them (for highlight for instance)
- access data if I click on it

I tried three implementations :

- one through D3 to generate SVG
- one through D3 again to generate div that sorte of "emulate" circles
- one through [Fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/) to go through canvas

For the div solution, it's just ugly as my circles are not always perfectly circular.
For SVG and canvas, it's two slow to use it.

How can I do to improve performances without reducing the number of displayed circles and still have something that is good-looking ?

Comment: how on earth is anyone going to make sense of something that shows 10,000 objects? You need to rethink your UX

Comment: @RobertLongson : I make dataviz on astrophysic data. I need to show all "photos" taken by a satellite. I already aggregated data with identical coordinates, but I can't go further without loosing precision. Please take a look there before judging me : http://episteme.univ-nantes.fr/dev/skymap/0

Comment: From your post I gather that the div solution is performing well, it's just ugly. Do you have a demo we can look at in order to try and make it prettier? ;)

Comment: hum no way to do that easily sorry...

Comment: Are you sure that canvas is as slow as SVG? I reckon that this is very unlikely. If that's the case, you probably have a performance issue anywhere else in the code. Thus, I'd suggest you to show us how you appended those circles, with a [MCVE] if possible (actually, without the code, this question is off topic here, *"asking for a tutorial"*). However, as you just said in the comment above that this is not possible, this question cannot be answered, and I voted to close it.

Comment: To search 10000 object to find the closest to the mouse ~0.100ms on average using a simple min distance search, 100,000 ~1ms easy realtime rate  . To draw 10000 individually coloured circles 20 pixel radius 189ms way to slow. Solution draw circles onto offscreen canvas only when needed. Draw that canvas on display canvas and highlight circles on the onscreen canvas as needed to get 100,000plus with annotated / highlighted mouse over circle at 60fps.

Comment: Solution two, use WebGL to render 10000 points in realtime.

Comment: It is possible to use D3 with Canvas, but you would need to rewrite a bunch of code!

Answer (score 1):

What's probably slowing you down is the detection of mouse-object overlap, which is a very general functionality of the browser and therefore is not particularly optimized. Good news is you can optimize that easily yourself. Consider this approach:

- Render the circles into a canvas. The canvas will be static throughout the interaction. No need to redraw it contents.
- The detection if a mouse is over a circle is easy to implement on your own. You know the positions of the circle centers, you know the position of the mouse, you know the math. Therefore you can search the circle(s) under mouse cursor yourself.
- Furthermore, you can utilize e.g. [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) structure to organize the circle centers into a hierarchical structure to hugely speed up the search process.
- Instead of changing CSS of a circle under mouse cursor you can just draw another circle on top of it. Do this in a separate `div` over the `canvas` so that the underlying `canvas` doesn't need to be redrawn.

Comment: Actually I guess what slows down my app is the binding circle-data. By using only canvas2D without interaction, it works well. So I think there's no out-of-the-box solution for me :)

Comment: Of course, there might be other bottlenecks in your code. It's hard to tell without looking into it. But 10.000 elements in a markup structure (be it HTML or SVG) are going to be a performance hog either way. Good luck and come back if you need further help.